# include_recipe makes everything before to be skipped

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I want to use postgresql community cookbook, but I want packages from a different repo. That's why I add it with `yum_repository` resource in my wrapper cookbook. Here is my wrapper cookbook recipe:

```
yum_repository 'PostgresBDR' do
  description 'Postgres BDR repo'
  baseurl 'http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-bdr94-2ndquadrant/yum/redhat-$releasever-$basearch'
  gpgkey 'http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-bdr94-2ndquadrant/RPM-GPG-KEY-2NDQ-BDR-94'
  action :create
end

node.default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.4'
node.default['postgresql']['server']['service_name'] = 'postgresql-9.4'
node.default['postgresql']['server']['packages'] = %w(postgresql-bdr94-server postgresql-bdr94-bdr)
node.default['postgresql']['client']['packages'] = %w(postgresql-bdr94 postgresql-bdr94-devel)
node.default['postgresql']['setup_script'] = 'postgresql94-setup'

include_recipe 'postgresql::ruby'
include_recipe 'postgresql::server'
```

The problem is that BDR repo does not get added until I comment two latest strings with `include_recipe`.
So I can accomplish installation in two parts.

1. Comment two latest lines with `include_recipe` and apply cookbook
2. Uncomment and apply cookbook again

Why it does not work as I expect? Tried to move `yum_repository` into a separate recipe and `include_recipe` it too but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postgresql::ruby` recipe does the install at compile time instead of the usual converge time because of its intended use. You'll have to set up the repo at compile time too.

```
yum_repository 'PostgresBDR' do
  description 'Postgres BDR repo'
  baseurl 'http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-bdr94-2ndquadrant/yum/redhat-$releasever-$basearch'
  gpgkey 'http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-bdr94-2ndquadrant/RPM-GPG-KEY-2NDQ-BDR-94'
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:create)
```

You can find more detailed info on the two phases at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/.